# Reasons for Wi-Fi to be slower on Ubuntu compared to Windows?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 64 bit – dual boot on the same computer.

Connecting to the same wireless network. And it turns out that on Windows I get a more stable and stronger signal than on Ubuntu.

To my knowledge there's a router which serves as a gateway and then there's a cable connected to the router which goes further to ISP, so the results for both OS should be the same.

I've tested the issue on both OSs at various times and it gave me the same result.

The question is why? Why Ubuntu networking is worse than that of Windows?

Comment: You mean _all your testing_ could not determine the cause of the speed difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated correctly, the final connection speed relies on your connection to your ISP.

There are several software settings that can affect the signal. One of them is the Wireless standard being used, currently there are two main standards at use, N which is newer and faster, and G which is older and slower.

In many cases, the router will transmit with both of these standards - for compatibility reasons, and the OS has control over which standard to use. (if it's supported by your hardware of course).

This how it looks like in Windows-7 device manager:
[image: Wireless network card]

These options should also be available on Ubuntu, for some directions, try looking at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197585/how-do-i-force-my-wireless-card-to-use-mode-802-11n)

Comment: Cool, so mine should be Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n, which means that I should try to switch everything to B?

Comment: @den-javamaniac if you want to have the highest speed, you should aim at switching everything to N

Answer (score -1):

Since the hardware is the same and you are seeing the difference when running different *software* on the computer, then the *software* is the reason why "Ubuntu networking" is worse than that of windows.

To get a serious answer, include details such as:

- verison and model of the wireless router
- model and revision of network interface
- model and revision of the motherboard
- driver vendor and version used in Windows and Ubuntu